# I used nvm command but the current node version still remains first state

Tags: node.js, nvm

everyone. I need your help for using nvm & node.
I am running a vue.js & express project.
Front-end need node version 12 and back-end need 14.16.
I installed nvm and ran this command

```
nvm install 12
nvm use 12

node -v
```

result: v18.16.0

I can't understand why that node version still remains v18.16.0
Could you answer me if you know the reason?
Thanks

What command should I use to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you make sure that you have installed nvm correctly and according to the documentation?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I reinstalled node.js and nvm and now it works well.